# Not Expected Results in DynamoDB PutItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

**Q: How can I avoid inserting an item into a table, when I have a composite primary key?**

I could only find examples in the documentation with a single primary key (only a partition key, but not with a partition key AND a sorting key).

**Context:**

- My partition key is named PK and the sorting is named SK.
- My PK is a UUID, SK is composed of a random bucket [0-9] e.g., "user#info#3", (3 is the random bucket).
- The same PK may appear multiple times, but SK for each of those repetitions will always be different.
- I want to insert the item in the table only when (PK is non-existent) OR (PK is existent AND SK doesn't begin with user#info)

**What I expect vs my outcome**

- `[outcome: expected - the item was not inserted]` If I try to insert an item with an existent PK, and exact SK (e.g., inserting user#info#3, and user#info#3 already exists), the item should NOT be inserted.
- `[outcome: NOT expected - the item was inserted]` If I try to insert an item with an existent PK, and non-exact SK (e.g., inserting user#info#3, and user#info#5 already exists), the item should NOT be inserted.
- `[outcome: expected - the item was inserted]` If I try to insert an item with a non-existent PK, the item should be inserted.

I'm using this command line snippet (modified from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html)) to insert data into the table:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name Users \
    --item file://item.json \
    --condition-expression "attribute_not_exists(PK) OR NOT begins_with(SK, :sk)" \
    --expression-attribute-values file://values.json
```

item.json

```
{
    "PK": {
        "S": "910cc6dd-b7e2-4286-89d4-db3d0e3fde6b"
    },
    "SK": {
        "S": "user#info#4"
    },
    "Name": {
        "S": "Greg"
    }
}
```

values.json

```
{
    ":sk": {
        "S": "user#info"
    }
}
```

If I remove the PK condition, and try to check only against the SK condition, it inserts the item (I'd expect it to NOT insert the item), e.g.:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name Users \
    --item file://item.json \
    --condition-expression "NOT begins_with(SK, :sk)" \
    --expression-attribute-values file://values.json
```

The above inserts the item, even though there is another item in the table that begins with `user#info`

Comment: This isn't how DynamoDB works. Can you just make your sort key `user#info` and move the number to a different attribute?

Comment: The reason I added the random bucket number is because the cardinality in SK is low, and data is skewed (other values are way more common). To support multiple query patterns, I need to use SK as the PK in a GSI view, so to not overload a single partition with queries, I add the random bucket. Can you explore why you say this is not how DynamoDB works, and what exactly "this" in your comment mean?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included more details. DynamoDB writes operate on individual documents only. Your question implies that you want it to perform the write conditionally based on a query of all documents with the same partition key; it doesn't/can't do that, the operation only 'sees' the document with the exact PK + SK combination.

Comment: As an aside, if the number of buckets is fixed and small enough, you may be able to accomplish this with a transaction that contains a condition check for each possible bucket. This will be expensive, however.

Comment: Oh, that makes much sense. This is an infrequent query, so your suggestion could fit well. Thanks for the insight.